# Is there a way to report on PRs in Azure Devops? (time to resolve, number of comments, report over a period of time

Tags: azure-devops, report, pull-request

I am noticing that we have a problem with PRs, they are taking too long to resolve, sometimes more time than it takes to actually implement the Story.  I want to be able to quantify the problem so that I can present it to the business and get buy-in on working on a solution.

Comment: There may be apis you can use to get the info you need, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20statuses?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)